# Import-DscResource with relative paths

Tags: powershell, import, dsc

i'm a newbie in powershell, since one day i'm searching for a solution to import dscresources in powershell from a relative path. I don't want that everyone who execute the file needs to have the modules in the powershell modules folder.

instead of

```
Import-DscResource -Name Test
```

something like this

```
Import-DscResource -Name Test -Path "../Modules/Test"
```

can anyone help me?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Import-DscResource by path does not work. You can place the module under Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules and specify the module name in the -Module parameter